# Project structure / architecture for shared or partial views

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm an experienced asp.net web forms dev but I'm new to MVC looking for some guidance in how to setup my MVC project. In my MVC 5 project I would like to create the following:

1. A basic data entry page which allows a user to edit their profile details. This page could be used by the user at any time while on the site.
2. A wizard page (or set of pages) that would include a step for the user to enter their profile details. All users will be required to go through the wizard upon first login.

I would like to build the profile editor as a partial view (or something like an asp.net user control) and just re-use it on both the wizard page and the stand alone profile editor page.  After reading this article (https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp-net/tips-and-tricks-about-razor-partial-views/) it appears that partial views may be helpful for reusing the code.

**MY QUESTION**: How should I structure my controllers / code that will actually take the data entered by the user in the partial view and submit it into the database.  Will each separate page require its own controller with duplicated code for saving the data to the db? Can a partial view have its own controller or code behind? Links to any articles or tutorials would be appreciated.

I have several other steps in my wizard which will reuse code/controls from other pages so I'm hoping to find a good pattern for this kind of code reuse.

Thanks,
Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Will each separate page require its own controller with duplicated code for saving the data to the db?

They need their septate controllers or at least their separate actions, but you should share the code for saving the data to db, for this check the repository pattern.

> Can a partial view have its own controller or code behind?

Yes, but for this scenario its not the best option.

> Links to any articles or tutorials would be appreciated.

Best resource is probably the Microsoft's own docs:
[Docs homepage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/index#pivot=aspnet), [basic stuff](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/index) and specially [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-basic-crud-functionality-with-the-entity-framework-in-asp-net-mvc-application) to understand the CRUD in ASP.NET MVC.

And for sharing a create/edit form you can use `editor templates`, like this:

`ProfileModel.cs`

```
public class ProfileModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

you should create an `EditorTemplate` in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/Profile.cshtml`

```
@model ProfileModel

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
```

And use it like this in your views:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Profile)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you an answer considering each of your questions..

> How should I structure my controllers / code that will actually take
>   the data entered by the user in the partial view and submit it into
>   the database.

You may separate your controllers based on the ui specific concerns of your application: for example, in your case you need to manage a user profile editing form, that we can consider an Account management concern element. So you may create a more general Account controller class into which implement the specific user profile actions that will be responsible to manage interaction between Model and Views.

> Will each separate page require its own controller with duplicated
>   code for saving the data to the db?

As just indicated it won't required.. you just need to implement some actions of its specific concern related controller and reuse that actions for every view or partial view that needs that specific logic and respects the action method requirements.

> Can a partial view have its own controller or code behind?

It is sufficient a generic object to manage its behaviour. As far as this concern, you may implement the very good model view viewmodel pattern.. in particular this pattern focuses attention on viewmodel objects, that are nothing but some dto to communicate from views and actions back and forth, and that will be the "model" bound at the view's ui forms.